# JAX-RS: HTTP 400 Bad Request when uploading file

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to upload a file via REST API.

```
@POST
@Path("/{fileName}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response uploadResource(@PathParam("fileName") String fileName,                               
                               @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream) {
        saveFile(fileName, uploadedInputStream);
        return Response.ok("Done!").build();
}
```

My Response:

```
javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
```

Headers:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
```

I debugged my code and found that `uploadResource` not invoked. The others methods like `GET` work fine. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The Content-Type should have  a boundary. See [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2). Are you sure you are sending the request as multipart? What client are you using? Can you show any relevant client code